# Postgres 11 - Fetching results after a transactiom

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, npgsql

With the recent update of [Postgres 11](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1855/). It now supports procedures. Transactions are finally supported in stored procedures in Postgres. However, I have been trying to perform a transaction and retrieving a refcursor as the result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testproc(pid text,pname text,INOUT cresults refcursor)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$

BEGIN
 cresults:= 'cur';  
 begin
    update "testtable" set id=pid , name=pname where id=pid;
  commit;
 end;
    OPEN cresults for select * from oureadata.CMS_CATEGORY limit 1;
end;
$procedure$
```

I understand that fetching of refcursor have to be in a transaction. This is how i execute the procedure.

```
BEGIN;
Call oureadata.testproc('1','2','');
fetch all in cur;
commit;
```

When i try to fetch the cursor, it throws an exception "ERROR: Invalid transaction termination"

---

But if i remove the commit from the procedure. I can actually execute the procedure and fetch the result of the refcursor. (The above is just an example, as i have other more complex transaction which will return refcursor after)

So my question is, can a procedure return a INOUT refcursor result after a transaction is done?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, in order to use the cursor after your procedure ends, you need to be on the same transaction you was when calling the procedure.
Your code use two different transactions: the first one is started with `BEGIN` just before calling the procedure, and it ends at the `COMMIT`. The second transaction starts automatically after the `COMMIT` in your procedure and continue until the `COMMIT` after your `FETCH`.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the requirement to be on the same transaction by writing a bash script which executed my SQL scripts using PSQL. It seems to work ok. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58022481/494635